# How to debug Octopress markdown source files?

Tags: debugging, markdown, jekyll, octopress

I use [Octopress](http://octopress.org) for blogging. Generally it works well except one occassion -- after typing `rake generate`, I got depressing output which says something like:

```
psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 6 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I can't remember how many times I've encounterd this situation. Every time I google the key words above, but got nothing help.

What I can do is to exclude all the source files (*.mkd) from `_posts`, and add them one by one to check which one goes wrong.  I keep checking, and finally it turns out that a minor *grammer mistake* makes octopress angry.

Life should NOT be that hard. So is it possible to *debug* a octopress source file to show **which line** of file is incorrect in grammer? The outputs from `rake generate` don't make sense at all.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Don't bother to debug Octopress. Please migrate to [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.0/index.html) -- a Python-powered static site generator. It is full-featured, easy to use, and no doubt,  generating useful debug information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be wrong JAML in the top part of the post (e.g. ':' in the title), see https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/549 for more info.

Comment: u sure it's `JAML` and not `YAML`?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar error ("mapping values are not allowed in this context") when I try to convert markdown files, using Pandoc. Perhaps your error message is coming from pandoc somehow?